# How do you answer a question that got moved to site unix.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, accepted-answer

I had a question about AIX and it got moved to unix.stackexchange.com before I could accept an answer to it.  I don't have a problem with that except that it appears to not have "Accept as Answer" option.  As an effect, my "Accept Rate" is suffering.  Thanks!

The question is referenced [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20252/how-do-you-determine-if-aix-5-3-has-perl-installed).

Comment: Thank you for following up on your migrated question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to that site. Login with the same OpenID as your account on SF, it will ask if you want to link the accounts. If you already have an account there but it's not linked, add the OpenID from SF if you haven't already, then look at your user account, under Accounts you should see an option to link your accounts. You can then accept the answer on Unix.SE.